# UnSupported Media Type when Calling REST Web Service

Tags: c#, rest

I am calling a REST web service which has given me this documentation

```
HTTP Method: POST 
Path: /commit/{path}/add-node  
Response Status 200, 302, 403, 404, 409, 503 

Form Parameters 
    - name : attribute name 
    - message : commit message
```

Based on this documentation. I have written following C# code.

```
  string restUrl = webServiceurl + "/commit/" + path + "/add-node";
  restUrl = restUrl + "?name=" + nodeName + "&message=" + commitMessage;
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(restUrl);
  request.Method = "POST";
  request.ContentType = @"application/json";
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()) {
      using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
        output = reader.ReadToEnd();
      }
    }
```

I also tried

```
  string restUrl = webServiceurl + "/commit/" + path + "/add-node";
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(restUrl);
  request.Method = "POST";
  request.ContentType = @"application/json";
  var param = new { name = nodeName, message = commitMessage };
  Stream reqStream = null;
  string output = null;
  try {

     byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(
                        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param)
                    );

    request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
    reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()) {
      using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
        output = reader.ReadToEnd();
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
      .....
  }
```

Unfortunately in both cases, I get 415 Unsupported Media Type in both cases. What is wrong with my code?

The web Services is a REST based web service written in Java.

Comment: Are you able to call the Java web service using Fiddler or a similar tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f5cd3961-5221-4c79-af1a-be7163694761/consume-a-restful-java-web-service-from-dotnet-code) the ContentType property may not be supported from the Java web service. Are you sure it accepts application/json?